# Mystical comma in a Python expression

Tags: python

I am wondering what the comma does in this code:

```
line, =
```

The following example shows the behavior:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
print("First:")
print(line)
print("Second:")
line = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
print(line)
```

Result:

```
First:
Line2D(_line0)
Second:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xb137c4c>]
```

It really becomes confusing when I try to use the line variable, and I don't know whether to use the trailing comma or not:

```
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
```

Or is there a better way to do this which avoids the comma?

Comment: This is useful when you have a container with a single item, instead of `x = L[0]`, you can just do `x, = L`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just unpacking a 1-tuple. eg:

```
line, = ('foo',)   # same as line = 'foo' in this example
```

compare with

```
line1, line2 = ('foo', 'bar') # unpack a 2-tuple
```

etc.

Comment: So that means that, returning "line," later on makes it a tuple again?

Comment: @DrJay yes, though people might just write `return (line,)` in that case.

Answer (score 4):

It's helpful for unpacking tuples

See the different results here:

```
a = (1,)
print(a) # prints (1,)

a,  = (1,)
print(a) # prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there's a short-hand to assign multiple variables at once:

```
(a, b, c) = something
```

You assign to a tuple of variables instead of a single variable. This example will raise an exception if `something` isn't a collection with exactly 3 elements; otherwise it will bind `a` to the first item in `something`, `b` to the second, and `c` to the third.

As you may know, in Python tuples the parentheses are usually optional; it's the commas that are important. So you could also write my example as:

```
a, b, c = something
```

And this of course works for any size tuple of variables, not just three. And 1-tuples are represented by having a single item with a tailing comma and nothing following<sup>1</sup>. So your example:

```
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
```

Is just asserting that `ax.plot([], [], lw=2)` returns a collection with a single element, and binding `line` to that element. It differs form the nearly identical statement:

```
line = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
```

because that would bind `line` to the collection itself, and contains no assertion about the number of elements it has.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a little ugly, but necessary because the only other obvious syntax would be `(item)`, which would clash with the syntax for simply parenthesising a sub-expression. E.g. nobody wants `2 * (3 + 1)` to give an error about multiplying an `int` and a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

It makes the variable the first (and in this case only) item in a tuple. This allows 'multuple' assignment such as:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

This is particularly useful for swapping values so, carrying on from the above, you could do:

```
a, b = b, a
```

And the `a` and `b` variable would swap values.